# Using NSRunLoop to block proceeding works on Simulator but fail on device

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here I have a UIAlertView,it appears within a NSRunLoop, i want the program proceeding blocked when it appears, after i clicked the "OK" button, the program carries on. I tried 2 methods

1.in my LBAlertView.h

```
@interface LBAlertView : UIAlertView <UIAlertViewDelegate>
{
    BOOL isWaiting4Tap;
}

@property(nonatomic,assign) BOOL isWaiting4Tap;

- (void)showModal;

@end
```

in LBAlertView.m

```
- (void)showModal
{
    isWaiting4Tap = YES;
    [self show];
    while (self.isWaiting4Tap) 
    {
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate 
   distantFuture]];
    }
}
```

in delegate place

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    switch (alertView.tag) {
        case 0:
        {
            self.tipView.isWaiting4Tap = 0;
            [((LBSceneView*)self.delegate).theBall initBall];
        }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }  
}
```

where tipView is object of LBAlertView.

2.in LBAlertView.m

```
- (void)showModal
{    
    [self show];
    CFRunLoopRun(); 
}
```

in delegate place

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    switch (alertView.tag) {
        case 0:
        {
            CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent()); 
            [((LBSceneView*)self.delegate).theBall initBall];
        }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }  
}
```

Both methods works well on simulator but fails on device, the LBAlertView pops out over and over again, seems the program is not blocked at all, can anybody figure out why, thanks

Comment: This is insanity.  Just call the continuation logic inside the delegate.

Comment: Please give us reasons to help out here :) This is NOT a pattern we use nor see very often in iOS

Comment: why, i thought it was common solution, so how to block nsrunloop when an uialertview appears ?